# Ipod classic 6th generation 2nd version smart data results

Tags: hard-drive

I have just bought a second hand ipod classic 6th generation version 2 160gb and have done a smart data check on it. The main results are low but the temperature range and start stop rates seem high. Start / Stop 34985, temp current 31c, min 57c,max 254c. Should I be worried? It seems fine atm. Any help, gratefully received.

Comment: 34k isn't all that much, especially if it's a device that's at least 6 years old. You should be very worried about the max drive temp, as that's almost 500°F. (Just kidding, I very much doubt the iPod would still be alive if it were exposed to that kind of temps).